# Selecting names based on conditions in common

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am puzzled with finding a solution to a problem I have in google-sheets.

In column A I have a list of people. In column B I have each persons availability on Monday. 
First I am trying to find a way to select the person with the least free time that has at least 2 hour window open up. For example `Bob free at 2:00pm,3:00pm`and have his name listed at the top of column C.

For the next part I am trying to match people that have the same time window opened up. For example if mike has `1:00pm,2:00pm,3:00pm,4:00pm`His name will be selected as well since he has the 2 hour window of 2pm and 3pm in common with Bob. I am trying to have mike and any other person in common with Bobs time below his name in column C.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and what you have already tried

Comment: I was able to do the second part by using `=FILTER(A2:A10, Find(C$1, B2:B10))`. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/rt4lO) is an image of the result. However what I have written in cell C1 is just a placeholder to test if it works. I am still not sure how to select the persons time with the least availability. I would try to count for number of commas but that wouldent work in occasions where there is a gap in hours of free time such as 3pm,5pm. @RobinGertenbach

Comment: Are the times always consecutive or can it be that I am free from 6 yo 7, not at 6 but from 9 onwards?

Comment: When someone is recorded for an hour I am considering it as from the start of the hour to the end of the hour. For example, 2:00pm I am counting the person as free until 2:59pm. Yeah the 2 hour window I am trying to make it only count if the times are consecutive for example 5pm-6:59pm. A solution I was thinking of would be to have multiple if statements to count each combination of consecutive 2hr intervals and then to compare which person had the least as being the result. But I think my method would not be as elegant as more knowledgeable people.